# Get Text Value from a Knockout Dropdown

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdown for various image categories:

`<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: imageCategoryList, value: 'Category', optionsCaption: --Select Category--, optionsText: &#39;Category&#39;, optionsValue: 'Category', event: {change: GetImages}"  id="Category" name="Category"></select>`

In my Javascript, I'm trying to get the text value of whatever is selected in that dropdown, but I'm not sure how to do it. In my viewModel, I have

```
var img = self.imageCategoryList().Text
```

but that only returns "undefined". How do I get the selected text value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are trying to accomplish here...

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPP5Q/33/

The view...

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="
  options: imageCategoryList,
  value: selectedCategory,
  optionsCaption: '--Select Category--',
  optionsText: function(item){ return item.Category },
  event: {change: getImages}"
id="Category" name="Category"></select>
```

and the viewmodel...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  // this runs after the window loads
  var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.imageCategoryList = ko.observableArray([
      {
        Category: 'A',
        Text: 'CategoryA'
      },
      {
        Category: 'B',
        Text: 'CategoryB'
      },
      {
        Category: 'C',
        Text: 'CategoryC'
      }
    ]);

    self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();

    self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue.Text);
    });

    self.getImages = function(){};
  }


  var vm = new ViewModel();

  ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

Comment: I can't upvote you (I don't have enough reputation), but thanks so much!

Comment: When I try to replace `console.log(newValue.Text);` with something like `var txt = newValue.Text`, I get an undefined error for txt. How do I record the text of selectedCategory to use elsewhere?

Comment: It could just be the scope of your variable. Try assigning it to self.newTextValue instead of txt and see if you can access it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind your selected option to an observable.
Soo in you model you create:

```
self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
```

and in your select

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: imageCategoryList, value: selectedCategory, optionsCaption: --Select Category--, optionsText: 'Category', optionsValue: 'Category', event: {change: GetImages}"  id="Category" name="Category"></select>
```

And in your javascript you can access it like

```
var img = modelObject.selectedCategory();
```

this is not tested but it's a start.

Comment: What is the `modelObject`? I'm getting an undefined error.